# Where should Bash questions be posted?

Tags: discussion

There are a few Stack Exchange sites arguably appropriate to [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) programming/configuration questions. I've posted two different questions, [one on *Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872069) and  [another on *Ask Ubuntu*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571852), and have gotten great answers to both. There are also Bash posts on *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Is there a recommended place for Bash questions?

Comment: I'd say using a linux tag and asking about particular bash programming problems, would be perfectly OK for SO.

Comment: [bash.org?](http://www.bash.org/)

Comment: Unless you're scripting, ask on an appropriate support site (unix&linux, ubuntu, ask different, su).

Comment: Whichever has the most tolerant inhabitants.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Depends.

If you're talking about Bash programming **in general**, then [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is acceptable.

If you're talking about Bash programming **specific to Ubuntu**, then [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is acceptable.

If you're talking about **general Bash usage**, then [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is acceptable.

I'd encourage you also to avoid cross-posting, as that duplicates the question and fragments the information that could be very useful across two sites.

Comment: Well, that's at least more concise and helpful, than just `/dev/null`. +1

Comment: Is Unix & Linux the same answer as Ask Ubuntu then?

Comment: What about questions about bash *usage* as opposed to programming? For example, “how do I configure the tab completion to do *X*?” Where should questions like that be posted?

Comment: I can see how my original wording gave the appearance of cross-posting a single question. It's not what I meant. The question was edited to clarify (mostly by someone else, a little by me).

Comment: @aliteralmind:  No; Ask Ubuntu is specifically geared towards questions about Ubuntu.  Unix and Linux is a broader superset of that.

Comment: I think there's hardly any ubuntu specific bash questions. You'd better off posting it to Unix & Linux.

Comment: I've -1ed this answer because the poster may well not know whether their question is Ubuntu specific. Not to mention that the line between "bash usage" and "bash programming" is very fine.

Comment: @jpmc26:  If you're working on an Ubuntu machine and you want to write a bash script, it's a pretty safe bet that the question would be on-topic over there.  If you want to work with other derivatives then Unix & Linux is fine, too.  It's more or less a scenario in which one question is on topic in more than one place, which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @simonzack:  What about scenarios in which a command works one way on Ubuntu but another way in Debian?  It *can* happen.  Also, some commands may not exist in other *nixes but do in *buntu; `apt-add-repository` is one such command.

Comment: Also, your answer ignores Super User, where it could also be on topic.

Comment: @jpmc:  Actually, it's [explicitly off topic there.](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Makoto Wat: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash. Why would "general Bash usage" questions be off topic there?

Comment: @Makoto Sure it can happen but more commonly scripts can run on most linuxes.

Comment: @jpmc:  The question as stated regarded programming questions, which are explicitly off topic on Super User.

Comment: @Makoto I disagree since it also references "configuration," which may not be explicitly related to "programming." Nevertheless, your own answer expanded beyond programming questions, so I was pointing out that it left out an important option for this category that you decided to include. My point is this: deciding where to post is generally hard, and at least sometimes, distinguishing which options are valid requires knowledge beyond what the asker might have.

Comment: There is considerable overlap between all four.  "How do I replace a string in a number of files" has a number of canned solutions, but real-world requirements often touch on what is at least superficially programming-like skills.  I'm sure an Ubuntu user could get away with asking this on Ask Ubuntu, and it's close enough to "how do I use this thing" to be suitable for https://superuser.com/ (based on my limited usage of that site).

Comment: And let's not forget [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) for our brethren in OSX land, especially when their problem is about interfacing between Bash and the native tools of that platform.

Answer (score 12):

*I found this myself as a recurrent issue. What about ["Bash issue on MacOS X?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) or on ["Raspberri Py?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash). Beyond this particular case, you could easily find yourself many of those grey-area questions: to give just one other example a ["C++ programming question on Arduino?"](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)*

---

The easy answer is **ask where it is the *most* appropriate** or **ask where you will find the best experts** -- but it does not really provide any concrete advices when the OP has difficulties to pinpoint exactly *what* is his issue. As this is regularly the case for newcomers. An other option  would be to suggest to **look at the number of similarly tagged questions**. More there are questions with the same tags -- more you have chance to find a great community.

That being said, once you adhere to the *"do-not-cross-post"* mantra, posting on the "wrong" site shouldn't be such an issue as we can [migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) questions between sites of the network.

Unfortunately, the SE network has now grown to many overlapping sites -- but only 5 are suggested in the "Close > Off-Topic > Migration" dialog. Or do I missed "Ask Ubuntu" there ?

Allowing us to vote to migrate on any other site would be great. But, beyond the few ones where we regularly participate, most of us don't know exactly [what is the real perimeter of each sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) (not mentioning the UX issue). So it would be clever to somehow restrict list of possible destination sites that one can suggest. Based on the tags on the question ? Or should we only be able to suggest a migration to sites where we reached a certain rep level ?

Comment: Migration is a sticky topic and my impression is that it is, if not actively discouraged then at least a less desirable default action for most situations. All other things being equal, when a question is put `[on hold]`, it would be best if the OP familiarized with the suggested destination site for at least a few days, then tried again there with suitable adaptations to the destination site's climate and culture.

Comment: @tripleee I agree with you about "low quality" question. Never was migration a substitute to close in my mind. However, as far as I understand, the question here is _"Where should XYZ questions be posted?"_ assuming _XYZ_ is in the overlapping area between various sites. Given a decently good question posted about Bash on RPi.SE / Ask different / Ask Ubuntu / etc, I think migration, when done properly, should be the right tool for this question to get the deserved attention if it was not posted in the most appropriate SE site.

Answer (score 8):

- *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)*: if the question focuses on Unix/Linux conventions or tools. For instance, questions regarding script portability or the various flags that can be used with a tool.
- *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)*: if you're completely sure your question is Ubuntu-specific.
- *[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)*: if the question is about Bash as a programming language, e.g. "How do I emulate this [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) idiom in Bash?".

Questions about Bash scripting in general are a toss up between *Stack Overflow* and *Unix & Linux*; use your best judgment. *Someone* will think you're wrong no matter what, but don't cross-post unless your original question is closed as off-topic!